# How to take in information using an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java

I want to create a program where I ask the user to enter three details of three human beings, and then show it back to the user.

This is the solution I came up with, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Human {   
   int age;
   String name;
   String gender;   
}

public class Database {

   public static void main(String[] args) {     
      System.out.println("Please enter the information of ten people one by one.");

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      Human[] person = new Human[3];

      for(int i =0; i < person.length; i++){
          person[i].age = input.nextInt();
          person[i].name = input.nextLine();
          person[i].gender = input.nextLine();          
      }


      System.out.println("Here are the people that you entered: ");

      for(int i = 0; i <person.length; i++){
          System.out.println(person[i].age);
          System.out.println(person[i].name);
          System.out.println(person[i].gender);
      }

      input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Rather, does it tell you where the error is? Or what input are you getting? etc.

Comment: Can you explain the behaviour you're expecting and the behaviour you're actually getting, and what the problem really is?

Comment: The problem has been solved. The solution below is what I was intending my original program to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many people are you entering? ");
    int people = input.nextInt();
    Human[] person = new Human[people];

    for (int i = 0; i < people; i++) {

        System.out.println("Creating new human number : " + i);
        Human h = new Human();
        person[i] = h;

        System.out.print("Please enter an age: ");
        person[i].age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
        person[i].name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter a gender: ");
        person[i].gender = input.next();

    }

    System.out.println("Here are the people that you entered: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(person[i].age + " ");
        System.out.print(person[i].name + " ");
        System.out.println(person[i].gender);
    }

    input.close();

}
```

You never instantiate a new `Human` object and put it into the array, so when you do `person[i]` you are accessing a null pointer. In the above code, I instantiate the object with

```
Human h = new Human();
```

and then put it into the array with

```
person[i] = h;
```

This will fix the null pointers. I also fixed the reading logic as well, so it will loop as many times as you enter asking for the information each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can you briefly explain what "throws exception" does?

Comment: Ahh sorry about that, that is left over code. I use the same file for writing tests for answers to questions on SO, so instead of a bunch of exception handling, I just have it throw any kind of exception. That code portion can be removed. When you add `throws [throwable type here]` to a function, it allows any exceptions that happen in that function to be thrown up a level (out of the function) and be caught and handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Human> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        list.add(new Human());
        System.out.print("Name: "); list.get(i).name = in.next();
        System.out.print("Age: "); list.get(i).age = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        System.out.print("Gender: "); list.get(i).gender = in.next();
    }
}
```

On this way it should work.

Comment: This code is using things I'm not really familiar with. I'll try it later on as I learn new things.

Comment: With which things aren't you familiar?

Comment: list.get whatever, arraylist, and in.next(). 
I'm doing a beginner course from Udemy, so I should learn it in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work just fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i <person.length; i++){
        System.out.println(person[i]);
    }
```

You are using a loop, so you really don't need to pull each property from the array they way you did before. If you are iterating through the array then the for loop is fine, otherwise get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate Human object to make it work

```
  for(int i =0; i < person.length; i++){
      person[i] = new Human();
      person[i].age = input.nextInt();
      person[i].name = input.nextLine();
      person[i].gender = input.nextLine();          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

`Human[] person = new Human[3];`

only allocates *space* to hold *references* to three `Human` objects. It doesn't create any `Human` objects. Initially, the entries in the array will be `null`. You still need to create each `Human`. For example, in your first loop you could write this at the beginning of it:

`person[i] = new Human();`